# How to Shuffle char From Array of Strings?

Tags: java, android

> i am trying to make game guess the word but I cant shuffle char from
>   array of string

```
 String names_ofcolor[] = {"red", "green", "blue"};

 int random = (int) (Math.random() * names_ofcolor.length);

    for (int j = 0; j < names_ofcolor[random].length(); j++) {


         Button btn = new Button(this);

        btn.setId(j);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn.setTextSize(16);
        linearlayout.addView(btn);
        btn.setText("" + names_ofcolor[random].charAt(j));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `List` of indices from `0` to `names_ofcolor[random].length() - 1` and shuffle it using `Collections::shuffle`. Then, you can use the shuffled indices to set the label of the button.

```
String names_ofcolor[] = { "red", "green", "blue" };

int random = (int) (Math.random() * names_ofcolor.length);
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < names_ofcolor[random].length(); i++) {
    indices.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(indices);
for (int j = 0; j < names_ofcolor[random].length(); j++) {    
    Button btn = new Button(this);    
    btn.setId(j);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setTextSize(16);
    linearlayout.addView(btn);
    btn.setText("" + names_ofcolor[random].charAt(indices.get(j)));
}
```

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names_ofcolor[] = { "red", "green", "blue" };

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * names_ofcolor.length);
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < names_ofcolor[random].length(); i++) {
            indices.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(indices);
        for (int j = 0; j < names_ofcolor[random].length(); j++) {
            String label = "" + names_ofcolor[random].charAt(indices.get(j));
            System.out.print(label);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
regne
```

**Another sample run:**

```
erd
```

**Another sample run:**

```
elbu
```

Comment: work very well but my button generate out of screen I cant make buttons gravity center in  LinearLayout

Comment: Great! That's a separate issue. I suggest you post a question specific to that problem.

Comment: how to remove last index , it's repeating

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: how can I stop repeating array